# css angular datatables designing

Tags: css, angularjs, datatables

i have these data on front end

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xq7a.jpg

i want that all check sign will be green 
 and here is my code

```
    $scope.dtColumnsCal= [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('Name')
    .renderWith(function(data, type, full){
    return "<a class='row-edit'>" +"<u>"+data+ " <i>" + (full.isDefault ? "(default)" : "") + "</i>"+"</u>" +"</a>";}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('description').withTitle('Description'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('weekStartDay').withTitle('Starting Day of Week')
    .renderWith(function(data,type,full){
        if(full.weekStartDay==1){
         return "Sunday"
        }
        if(full.weekStartDay==2){
         return "Monday"
        }
        if(full.weekStartDay==3){
         return "Tuesday"
        }
        if(full.weekStartDay==4){
         return "Wednesday"
        }
       if(full.weekStartDay==5){
         return "Thursday"
       }
       if(full.weekStartDay==6){
         return "Friday"
       }
       if(full.weekStartDay==7){
         return "Saturday"
       }
   }),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('M')
    .renderWith(function(data, type, full){
        return data.indexOf(2)!=-1 ? '\u2713': '\u2718';}
    ),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('T')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){ return data.indexOf(3)!=-1 ?  '\u2713' : '\u2718';}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('W')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){ return data.indexOf(4)!=-1 ?  '\u2713' : '\u2718';}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('T')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){ return data.indexOf(5)!=-1 ? '\u2713' : '\u2718';}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('F')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){ return data.indexOf(6)!=-1 ?  '\u2713' : '\u2718';}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('S')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){ return data.indexOf(7)!=-1 ?  '\u2713' : '\u2718';}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('S')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){return  data.indexOf(1)!=-1 ? '\u2713' : '\u2718';}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('').withTitle('Action').renderWith(function(data, type, full){
        return "<a class='row-def'  ng-model='click' ng-hide='click'><i ></i> <u>Set Default</u> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>"
        + "<a class='row-del'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i> Delete</a>";})
   ].map(function(value){return value.withOption('defaultContent', '')});
  $scope.dtInstanceCal={};

 }]);
```

you can see woking days column with unicode character value they are unicode character value  of check and cross sign .i want to change those color

Answer (score 0):

the problem has been short out 
here is code

```
   $scope.dtColumnsCal= [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('Name')
    .renderWith(function(data, type, full){
    return "<a class='row-edit'>" +"<u>"+data+ " <i>" + (full.isDefault ?"(default)": "") + "</i>"+"</u>" +"</a>";}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('description').withTitle('Description'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('weekStartDay').withTitle('Starting Day of Week')
    .renderWith(function(data,type,full){
        if(full.weekStartDay==1){
         return "Sunday"
        }
        if(full.weekStartDay==2){
         return "Monday"
        }
        if(full.weekStartDay==3){
         return "Tuesday"
        }
        if(full.weekStartDay==4){
         return "Wednesday"
        }
       if(full.weekStartDay==5){
         return "Thursday"
       }
       if(full.weekStartDay==6){
         return "Friday"
       }
       if(full.weekStartDay==7){
         return "Saturday"
       }
   }),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('M')
    .renderWith(function(data, type,full){
        return data.indexOf(2)!=-1 ? "<span style='color:#27C24C';>"+'\u2713'+"</span>":"<span style='color:#E48282;'>"+  '\u2718'+"</span>";}
    ),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('T')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){ return data.indexOf(3)!=-1 ? "<span style='color:#27C24C;'>"+ '\u2713'+"</span>" :"<span style='color:#E48282;'>"+  '\u2718'+"</span>";}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('W')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){ return data.indexOf(4)!=-1 ?"<span style='color:#27C24C';>"+'\u2713'+"</span>" : "<span style='color:#E48282;'>"+  '\u2718'+"</span>";}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('T')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){ return data.indexOf(5)!=-1 ?"<span style='color:#27C24C';>" +'\u2713'+"</span>" : "<span style='color:#E48282;'>"+  '\u2718'+"</span>";}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('F')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){ return data.indexOf(6)!=-1 ?"<span style='color:#27C24C;'>"+ '\u2713'+"</span>" : "<span style='color:#E48282;'>"+  '\u2718'+"</span>";}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('S')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){ return data.indexOf(7)!=-1 ?"<span style='color:#27C24C;'>" +'\u2713'+"</span>" : "<span style='color:#E48282;'>"+  '\u2718'+"</span>";}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('workingDays').withTitle('S')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full){return  data.indexOf(1)!=-1 ? "<span style='color:#27C24C;'>"+'\u2713'+"</span>" : "<span style='color:#E48282;'>"+  '\u2718'+"</span>";}),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('').withTitle('Action').renderWith(function(data, type, full){
        return "<a class='row-def'  ng-model='click' ng-hide='click'><i ></i> <u>Set Default</u> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>"
        + "<a class='row-del'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i> Delete</a>";})
   ].map(function(value){return value.withOption('defaultContent', '')});
  $scope.dtInstanceCal={};

  }]);
```